# Display of ColorPropertyDescriptor in properties view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have added a ColorPropertyDescriptor to the Shapes example in GEF, however this displays as "RGB {0, 0, 0}" when a shape is selected, and only changes to a ColorCellEditor with button on the right hand side and coloured button on the left hand side when the property is selected.

How do I display the ColorCellEditor even if the property is not selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: needed create new sub-class.

Use:

- `ColorPropertyDescriptor1 extends ColorPropertyDescriptor`

  - Method `ColorPropertyDescriptor1#getLabelProvider` should return `ColorPropertyLabelProvider`.
  - Method `ColorPropertyDescriptor1#createPropertyEditor` should return `ColorPickerCellEditor` to change representation when we click on property value.
- `ColorPropertyLabelProvider extends LabelProvider`
  Methods `ColorPropertyLabelProvider#getImage` and `ColorPropertyLabelProvider#getText` should return color square and comments. See `ColorPropertyDescriptor`.
- `ColorDialogCellEditor extends DialogCellEditor`. See `ColorCellEditor`.